# How do I reset/clear JRadioButton in Java

Tags: java, swing, jradiobutton

How do you reset/clear a `JRadiobutton`? clearing a `TextField` is as simple as `surenameField.setText("");` is there any similar way with the `RadioButton`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean

```
radioButton.setSelected(false);
```

?

Comment: Right on! I did this and it didn't work, but that was my fault. this works! Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

If you want to clear the text of a `JRadioButton` named `radio`, you would call `radio.setText("")`. If you want to de-select the button, you call `radio.setSelected(false)`. Note that this does not actually fire events, so if you have a listener registered to respond to de-select events, this won't notify that listener.

For more information, you can read the official documentation for `JRadioButton` here

[JRadioButton API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JRadioButton.html)

Answer (score 0):

Could you specify what you mean by "reset"?

The following things are possible:

- Remove the button from the program: you can do this by calling the remove method from its container (`[container].remove([radioButton]`, eg. `myPanel.remove(myRadioButton)`.
- Remove the text from the button: you can do this by doing what you set: `myRadioButton.setText("")`

Comment: by reset i mean that when I select one of two buttons I want it to be deselected (remove the "dot") after i press my "submit" button

Comment: Ah, ok. But I see someone else answered that already :)